# What does DBMSSOCN stand for?

Tags: sql-server, protocols

I know what it is, which is the Winsock TCP/IP protocol for database connections, just not what it is an acronym for.

Perhaps something like:

Data Base Micro Soft SOCket Network?

Seems a bit clunky.  I was working with a SQL trainee today, and realized I didn't actually know what it stood for.  Searching only turned up an explanation of the protocol and how it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Being Microsoft and all, we can't really know for sure *;)*

That being said, by looking at other similar libraries it looks like you hit the nail on the head:

```
dbnmpntw - Win32 Named Pipes
dbmssocn - Win32 Winsock TCP/IP
dbmsspxn - Win32 SPX/IPX
dbmsvinn - Win32 Banyan Vines
dbmsrpcn - Win32 Multi-Protocol (Windows RPC)
```

(source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238949)